# how to combine Facebox and OnselectedIndex function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem where I don't know how to combine between Facebox and OnselectedIndex function in asp.net.

Here is my code.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" class="table table-bordered data-table" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" > 
            <columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Request ID" DataField="reqID"><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Username" DataField="reqName" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Department" DataField="reqDept" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Categories" DataField="reqCategories" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="reqType" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="reqDesc" /> 
              <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"><ItemTemplate><a runat="server" href="#info" rel="facebox" >More</a></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
           </columns></asp:GridView>
```

Here is my facebox code :

```
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView2"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" class="table table-bordered data-table"> 
            <columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Request ID" DataField="reqID" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Verified By" DataField="verifiedBy" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Verified Date" DataField="verifiedDate" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Approved By" DataField="approvedBy" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Approved Date" DataField="approvedDate" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Accepted By" DataField="acceptedBy" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Accepted Date" DataField="acceptedDate" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Done By" DataField="doneBy" />
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Done Date" DataField="doneDate" />
           </columns></asp:GridView>
```

and here is my OnSelectedIndexChanged code :

```
 Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim id As String
    id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text

    conn.Open()
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM ticketList where reqID = '" & id & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Close()
        GridView2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
        GridView2.DataBind()
    End If
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Any idea when I click "More" then it will go to OnSelectedIndexChanged function and show data in my facebox?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged` to the code:

```
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim id As String
    id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text

    conn.Open()
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM ticketList where reqID = '" & id & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn)
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Close()
        GridView2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
        GridView2.DataBind()
    End If
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```